# Handling Special Characters: '\n', '\\n', '\t' and '\\t' when reading a file in java

Tags: java

I have a text file named `myfile` with one line text, containing some specials characters `\n` (new line character) or some escaped of this characters `\\n`,

myfile content:

```
thiss is\n a string\\n bla bla
```

I want to read this file but keep the semantic meaning of these special characters.

I tried to read the file without any special work, but all these special characters are interpreted as a raw string.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = Main.class.getResource("/myfile").getPath();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(path))) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(line); // printed as a raw string, `\n` not interpreted as a new line char
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using the `String.replace()` method, but it only works for `\n` but not for `\\n`.

```
line.replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Comment: You'll need to do a more complicated replace.  You can do a regex on `\n` where the preceding char is not \  (like `[^\\]?\\n`) and then a subsequent pass to replace `\\(escapeable char)` with `\(escapeable char)`

Comment: @possum Thank you for your reply ! I tried using your regex with `String.replaceAll()` method, but like the https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) indicates that there is a problem when using '\' in a regex, and I don't know how to handle this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String in = "thiss is\\n a st\\tring\\\\n bla bla";
    String out = in
        .replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\n", "\n")
        .replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\t", "\t")
        .replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\");
    System.out.println("in  : " + in);
    System.out.println("out : " + out);
}
```

output:

```
in  : thiss is\n a st\tring\\n bla bla
out : thiss is
 a st   ring\n bla bla
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually do:

```
line = line.replace("\\\\n", "\n");
line = line.replace("\\n", "\n");
```

in that order.

Comment: This is treating the escaped and unescaped the same.  They asked to "keep the semantic meaning the same" which would be to have the escaped versions show up as the text "\n"

Comment: That's true, you're right.